# pandas extensions usage without importing it

Tags: python, pandas, import

I have created pandas extensions as mentioned [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor.html#pandas.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor).

The extending classes are defined in a module named <kbd>pd_extensions</kbd>, and I would like to use them in a different module <kbd>my_module</kbd> for example. The two modules are in the same package called <kbd>source</kbd>.

currently to be able to use the extensions Im importing the <kbd>pd_extensions</kbd> module into <kbd>my_module</kbd> like this:

`import source.pd_extensions`

is there a way to use the extensions I created without importing the module?

I find myself importing this module to every module that I want to use the extensions in the package, and I thought there might be a better way of doing it (maybe through the <kbd>_ _ init _ _</kbd> module).

I tried just using the extensions without importing the module they are defined in, but it did not work obviously.

I'm thinking about importing it in the  <kbd>_ _ init _ _</kbd> file so all the modules in the package would have access to it without having to import it themself, but I can't figure out if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can import the extension module in `__init__` file since the extension module will first import pandas and then register the accessor therefore the pandas module will be cached in `sys.modules` and any subsequent import to pandas from other modules will simply retrieve the entry from the cache.

here is the simple example:

```
source
├── __init__.py
├── my_module.py
└── pd_extension.py
```

The following are the contente of the files:

```
# pd_extension.py
import pandas as pd

@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor('spam')
class Spam:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self.df.shape
```

---

```
# my_module.py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print(df.spam.shape)
```

---

```
# __init__.py
import source.pd_extension
```

Now lets test the code by executing `my_module.py` which works as expected

```
$ python -m source.my_module
(2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I have been looking for.

Comment: By the way, can you refer me to where I can read more about how sys.modules works? 
[here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) it doesn't specify much.

Comment: Of course! You can read more about the modules cache in the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to add it to pandas's `__init__.py` and just import pandas but I would first create a virtual environment before you do that.

Here is how you can go about it using conda

```
conda create -n test_env python=3.10
conda install pandas
```

navigate to the pandas folder in `test_env`

```
/Users/.../opt/anaconda3/envs/test_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py
```

at the bottom of the `__init__.py` I added

```
import pandas as pd


@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("geo")
class GeoAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj

    @property
    def center(self):
        # return the geographic center point of this DataFrame
        lat = self._obj.latitude
        lon = self._obj.longitude
        return (float(lon.mean()), float(lat.mean()))

    def plot(self):
        # plot this array's data on a map, e.g., using Cartopy
        pass
```

Now you should just be able to do

```
(base) ~ % conda activate test_env          
(test_env) ~ % python
Python 3.10.9 (main, Jan 11 2023, 09:18:20) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ds = pd.DataFrame({"longitude": np.linspace(0, 10),
...                    "latitude": np.linspace(0, 20)})
>>> ds.geo.center
(5.0, 10.0)
>>>
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, but it involves changing the source code of pandas, and when others will work with the package  I'm building they will have to do so manually as well.
is there a way other than that to do so?